# datetime Cast or Convert?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What to choose: `Cast` or `Convert` for datetimes (Microsoft SQL Server)?

---

I have had a look at the [MSDN Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). At the first glance it seems there is no difference, except for the syntax:

**Syntax for CAST:**

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
```

**Syntax for CONVERT:**

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

And **CAST** is ANSI-standard, which makes it more portable accross different database platforms.

Comment: @Learner I asked about datetime casts / converts, not generally. Because'Convert' is more flexible to convert to format dates.

Comment: @FabianBigler Part of the problem is this is opinion based, when I use cast or convert might be different from when someone else uses it.

Comment: @bluefeet I don't ask for subjective answers though. I ask for pragmatic thinking.

Comment: The way you worded the question is subjective though _When would you choose Cast over Convert_.

Comment: What is the point of asking this specifically in connection with `datetime`? The accepted answer to the question linked covers everything that you need to know: CAST is ANSI, CONVERT more flexible. When ANSI compliance is the priority, use CAST. When you need flexibility, use CONVERT.

Comment: @AndriyM I didn't conclude that for both things apply the same rules. I could imagine there was some other differences why to choose one or the other. Now my doubts have disappeared - thank you.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks I changed it to "What to choose...?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`convert` has an optional parameter `style`, and I suggest to use `convert` instead of `cast`. It helps to avoid confusion.
For example, if you write `cast('20130302' as date)`, what would you get? March 2 or February 3?

Also, if you want specific format when casting to date to string, you bound to use `convert`

Comment: +1 for nice example 'cast('20130302' as date)'

Comment: If you cast `cast('20130302' as date)`, I expect you get 2013-03-02, so 2013 March, 02. Always.

Comment: Actually, you chose a bad example to make your case. The `YYYYMMDD` format would *always* be interpreted unambiguously in SQL Server, and so `'20130302'` would convert as March 2, 2013 without a format specifier.

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, you right, I've just wanted to point it out that YYYYMMDD is ISO format in SQL Server, but you was faster. Anyway, I think that my point about `cast` and `convert` for date/datetime is clear enough. I'll try to use yyyy-mm-dd if I have to give an example in the future :)

Comment: Yes, or with something like `07/05/12`.

Comment: @RomanPekar that's quite easy, you will always get March 2. YYYYDDMM doesn't exist as a standard, YYYYMMDD does!

Answer (score 3):

The [MSDN Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) link that you have posted, If you read carefully you will find your answer under section G:

```
G. Using CAST and CONVERT with datetime data
```

***The following example displays the current date and time, uses CAST to change the current date and time to a character data type, and then uses CONVERT display the date and time in the ISO 8901 format.***

```
SELECT 
   GETDATE() AS UnconvertedDateTime,
   CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(30)) AS UsingCast,
   CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126) AS UsingConvertTo_ISO8601  ;
GO
```

Here is the result set.

```
UnconvertedDateTime       UsingCast                       UsingConvertTo_ISO8601

----------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------

2006-04-18 09:58:04.570   Apr 18 2006 9:58AM              2006-04-18T09:58:04.570
```

(1 row(s) affected)

You can clearly see the difference.

### Update

**Check this:** http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/21/sql-server-display-datetime-in-specific-format-sql-in-sixty-seconds-033-video/

Comment: Thank you. I have already seen the difference between cast and convert as you mentioned, in the MSDN Specifications. But that is not answering my question when to use which one.
Is there no rule of thumb in which cases to use cast or convert?

Comment: From my understanding, there is no rule of thumb. I prefer to use Convert as it makes date formatting super easy.