# SQL Server convert ' dd/MM/YYYY H:mm:ss p.m..' to datetime

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I am importing a text column into a SQL Server 2008 database.

I have a field 'carcassdate' in the following format

'11/05/2017 9:18:46 a.m.'

'10/05/2017 1:08:27 p.m.'

etc. How can I convert this into a proper SQL Server 2008 datetime (24 hour) column please?

I can't seem to find a proper solution for this.

My desired result is

'11/05/2017 9:18:46 a.m.'  converted to 2017-05-11 09:18:46.000

'10/05/2017 1:08:27 p.m.'  converted to 2017-05-10 13:08:27.000

Thanks in advance.

What I have tried so far:
strip the date part of the column

```
select  convert(date, convert(varchar(10),carcass_date)) as carcassdate
```

That's the easy part..But I'm struggling with the time part.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `cast(replace(carcass_date, '.', '') as datetime)`

Comment: wow.. really.. that simple! Thank you so much.I can accept this as the answer if you make it an answer rather than a comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the periods in the string. By removing them, you can cast the string as a datetime. e.g.:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(carcass_date, '.', '') AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: I just tested on my system and a value of `'05/11/2017 9:18:46 a.m.'` returns 11th May which is the incorrect value.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That would depend on your DATEFORMAT settings... e.g. DMY vs MDY. 05/11/2017 _is_ the 11th of May if you're using MDY...

Comment: It appears the only solution not dependent on an external config is `convert`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, but that also requires already knowing the format your dates are going to be in. e.g. If they are being entered as MM/DD/YYYY (101), then converting them to 103 is going to give you the incorrect dates. Casting with your default DATEFORMAT seems like the correct option to me, but I can see why you might think differently.

Comment: But we _do_ already know what the format it's in. If we didn't, cast still wouldn't be any better! Just trying to promote defensive coding here. Why suggest a method that gives you a different result depending on server config (cast) when you could use a method that produces the same result every time regardless (convert)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The point is that yes, it gives a different result depending on the configuration, but that isn't necessarily a bad thing because the default configuration more than likely matches the input. On the other hand, if I convert the date with the third parameter 103, then I've guaranteed that I get the wrong date if my strings are in MM/DD/YYYY format. I think it's wiser to assume the input matches the default configuration of a server than to assume it will always be a particular way, but as I said, I can see why you might think differently.

Comment: LOL, I respectfully, but completely disagree. :)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to date conversion, I suggest that you always be explicit.

Any kind of programming that is not explicit about date formats invites bugs.

I suggest you *Never* use `cast` as there is no explicit format. Even though it always assumes ISO format, I've never found any info about how it decides other formats (including your which is not ISO)

*Never* use `convert` without a format number.

I suggest you instead use `convert` with a format number. On my system, this returns *two different dates*. **Cast returns the wrong one.**

```
DECLARE @D AS VARCHAR(100) = '05/11/2017 9:18:46 a.m.'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(@D, '.', ''), 103) as converted

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@D, '.', '') AS DATETIME) as casted
```

Number 103 is defined as dd/mm/yyyy format. At least this way you have some degree of self documentation - that's the format you expect

Later versions of SQL have `parse` but it uses cultures, not format strings.

Perhaps read this

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/

There's also a non-decisive discussion here:

[datetime Cast or Convert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433478/datetime-cast-or-convert)

Comment: Thanks Nick. As you have suggested, I have used the convert(datetime.. option for certainty.